# How can I assign some XML value to a JavaScript var?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to assign a value that is in my xml to a variable in javascript... Is this somehow possible?? My idea is to display links in the last column of the generated table. This is my approach but I'm not sure it will work.. If anyone has a better idea pls share :D

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script>
                var ahref = '<xsl:value-of select="url"/>'; <----- How to achieve this???
            </script>
            <h2>My Catalog</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9ACD32">
                    <th>Album</th>
                    <th>Artist</th>
                    <th>Link</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="catalog/album">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
                        <td><a href="" id="ahref" style="padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;">link</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
            <script>
                document.getElementById("ahref").href = ahref;
            </script>
       </body>
   </html>
</xsl:template>
```

here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="catalog.xsl"?>

<catalog>
    <album>
        <title>Exodus</title>
        <artist>Bob Marley</artist>
        <country>Jamaica</country>
        <price>19,99</price>
        <url>https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp</url>
    </album>
    <album>
        <title>Black Album</title>
        <artist>Metallica</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <price>20,00</price>
        <url>https://www.artstation.com/artist/lanyuan</url>
    </album>
    <album>
        <title>Nevermind</title>
        <artist>Nirvana</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <price>22,00</price>
        <url>http://fontawesome.io/icon/external-link</url>
    </album>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need Javascript, if you change

```
            <xsl:for-each select="catalog/album">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
                    <td><a href="" id="ahref" style="padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;">link</a></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

to

```
            <xsl:for-each select="catalog/album">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
                    <td><a href="{url}" style="padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;"><xsl:value-of select="url"/></a></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

then the HTML resulting from the XSLT transformation of your XML document will contain a link in the third table cell of each row.